# Javascript - Flood-Fill and scanLine algorithms are line-based floods but I want square based floods

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

I have a flood-fill algorithm ([Flood-fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)) to fill a 24x24 matrix. I would like to draw a shape as similar to a square using exactly cspots spots for each group as cspots can contain any number. The total of all groups cspots value will equal (24*24) so as the drawing progresses, the areas will become less and less square-like but I would like to keep the semblance of a square. In this example, there are 10 groups of varying cspots values and they need to be all drawn within the 24*24 matrix as square-like as possible. Matrix is 24x24 here but will be bigger with more groups in production. Code:

```
Main code:

  var cspots,    // number of spots per group
      gArr=[];   // global array which contains all group spots

  var tArr = new Array(gArr.length);   // touch array for flood-fill
  for(var spot in inArr) {
    for (var tspot in tArr)  // initialise touch array 
      tArr[tspot]=0;
    for(gspot in gArr) {     // find lowest open y*24+x ordinal
      if (gArr[gspot][0] == 0) 
        break;
      tArr[gspot]=1;
    }
    cspots = inArr[spot].GD;
    userFill(gArr[gspot][1],gArr[gspot][2],inArr[spot].KY,tArr);
  }

function userFill(x,y,elem,tArr) {
  var gord, qt=0;
  if (!cspots) return;
  if ((x >= 0) && (x <= 23) && (y >= 0) && (y <= 23)) {
    gord = y*24 + x;
    if (gArr[gord][0] != 0 || tArr[gord]) 
      return;
    gArr[gord][0] = elem;
    tArr[gord] = 1;
    --cspots;
    userFill(x+1,y,elem,tArr);
    userFill(x-1,y,elem,tArr);
    // before the y-change we need to see if there are any open spots on this line
    for(gord=y*24; gord<=(y*24)+23; gord++) {
      if (gArr[gord][0] == 0) {
        qt=1;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!qt) {
      userFill(x,y+1,elem,tArr);
      userFill(x,y-1,elem,tArr);
    }
  }
};
```

This is a standard flood-fill recursive algorithm (with an accompanying touch array to mark any touches) with the additional code that I check if all x-values are set to non-zero on each x-plane before changing the y-value. This produces a matrix like this:

[image]

The problem is that it doesn't look very good (imo) as most of the areas are strung-out along the x-plane. What I want is each different group area to be in the shape of a square as much as I can. Sort-of like this example (using letters to indicate the different group areas):

```
V V V W W W W X X X X X
V V Y W W W W X X X X Z
Y Y Y W W W W Z Z Z Z Z
Y Y   W W W W Z Z Z Z Z
... and so on
```

So I have changed the userFill to look at a boxX variable which is just the (sqrt of each area)+1, which hopefully I can use to limit each area to make a square-shape. And a preX variable to store the anchor point from each group area so I know how many spots have been added. Here's the new userFill:

```
Main code:

  var tArr = new Array(gArr.length);
  for(var spot in inArr) {
    for (var tspot in tArr)  // initialise touch array 
      tArr[tspot]=0;
    for(gspot in gArr) {     // find lowest open y*24+x ordinal
      if (gArr[gspot][0] == 0) 
        break;
      tArr[gspot]=1;
    }
    cspots = inArr[spot].GD;
    boxX = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(cspots));
    preX = gArr[gspot][1];
    userFill(gArr[gspot][1],gArr[gspot][2],inArr[spot].KY,tArr);
  }

function userFill(x,y,elem,tArr) {
  var gord, qt=0;
  if (!cspots) return;
  if ((x >= 0) && (x <= 23) && (y >= 0) && (y <= 23)) {
    gord = y*24 + x;
    if (gArr[gord][0] != 0 || tArr[gord]) 
      return;
    gArr[gord][0] = elem;
    tArr[gord] = 1;
    --cspots;
    // before the x-change we need to see if we have done a boxX number of changes to maintain square-shape
    if (Math.abs(x-preX) == boxX) {
      userFill(preX,y+1,elem,tArr);
      userFill(preX,y-1,elem,tArr);
      return;
    }
    userFill(x+1,y,elem,tArr);
    userFill(x-1,y,elem,tArr);
    // before the y-change we need to see if there are any open spots on this line
    for(gord=y*24; gord<=(y*24)+boxX; gord++) {
      if (gArr[gord][0] == 0) {
        qt=1;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!qt) {
      userFill(x,y+1,elem,tArr);
      userFill(x,y-1,elem,tArr);
    }
  }
};
```

The only difference is that I check if boxX spots have been added and then call userFill recursively to change the y-plane.

Here's the output and it looks better as most areas are square-like but obviously it needs work (missing most of the spots, pale-blue group area is very oddly-shaped and not square-like at all), but I wonder if there is a better algorithm out there that changes a flood-fill from line-based to square based.

[image]

**FIXED:**

I used a Breadth-First Search which created square-like structures for each group area. The code is:

```
function bfsFill(x,y,elem,tArr) {
  var gord, i=0, pt, queue=[], cnt=0;
  if (!cspots) return;
  if (isOutOfBounds(x,y)) return;
  queue.push([x,y]);
  while(cspots>0 && queue.length>0) {
    pt = queue.shift(); 
    gord = pt[1]*24 + pt[0];
    tArr[gord] = 1;
    gArr[gord][0] = elem;
    --cspots;
    var rArr = neighbours(pt);
    async.eachSeries(rArr, function(el, cb2) {
      if (!isOutOfBounds(el[0],el[1])) {
        gord = el[1]*24 + el[0];
        if (tArr[gord] == 0 && gArr[gord][0] == 0) {
          for(var qi in queue) {
            if (queue[qi][0] == el[0] && queue[qi][1]==el[1]) {
              cb2();
              return;
            }
          }
          queue.push(el);
        }
      }
      cb2();
    }, function(err) {
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: I find your question a bit hard to understand since it misses some initial problem exposition. Are you trying to fill an image starting from a number of seed points? Does the current image play any role in this? Why are the results you show not fully filled? Are you looking to generate a [Voronoi diagram with the Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram#Illustration)? Also, please add some explanation to your code. All those variables do not really have self-explanatory names and it is pretty hard to figure out what is going on.

Comment: @NicoSchertler. Yes, I am trying to fill an image with a different colour area for each group. One group may have 50 spots, another 6. The flood-fill algorithm is x-axis dominant so that the groups will be strung-out along the x-plane. I want the group areas to be square-shaped. The example images I used is a 24x24 matrix but in production the matrix will be much bigger (hence the empty space). The Voronoi diagram looks promising especially the Manhattan Distance approach which creates square-like areas. I added some comments and definitions.